# Regex to match a word or a dot

Tags: regex, r

This should be a fairly trivial question but I have spent quite some time and Im  unable to do it -

If this is my string -

```
"this/DT word/NN is/VBZ a/DT dot/NN ./."
```

I want to extract the immediate neighbors of `/` , be it a word,comma or a full stop.

`(\\w+)/(\\w+)` gives the words before n after `/` but not the full stops etc.

I tried this -  `"\\.\\/\\.|(\\w+)/(\\w+)"` for grabbing the full stops but doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help please.( I am trying this in R)

Thanks!

Comment: I m confused. Please tell what do you exactly expect to be extracted with regex from above sample input

Comment: Perhaps, `(\\S+)/(\\S+)`?

Comment: thanks  @stribizhev , that works! :)

Comment: I tried to explain the choice in my answer, and provided some alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\w` only matches letters, digits and an underscore. A dot/period belongs to punctuation and can be captured with Perl-like `\p{P}` or POSIX class `[:punct:]`. Thus, theoretically, you could use something like [`([\\w[:punct:]]+)/([\\w[:punct:]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gV6bN0/4) (or even a more POSIXish [`([[:alpha:][:punct:]]+)/([[:alpha:][:punct:]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/gV6bN0/4)), but I guess matching non-whitespace characters on both sides of `/` suits your purpose best.

Here is an alternative to the `(\\S+)/(\\S+)` regex:

```
([^\\s]+)/([^\\s]+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV6bN0/1)

The `[^\s]` means *any symbol other than a whitespace*. Note that `\S` means *any non-whitespace character.

If you can have no non-whitespace characters on either side of `/`, I believe

```
([^\\s]*)/([^\\s]*)
```

or

```
(\\S*)/(\\S*)
```

will work better for you since `*` will match *0 or more characters*.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV6bN0/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
"(\\S+)/(\\S+)"
```

i.e. grab each non-space text before and after `/`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA1nJ8/2)